# Getting object ID in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

Whenever an object is instantiated from a class I need to capture its  object ID. Is there any boost calls available that would help in catching this info?

```
Class1 obj1();
Class2 obj2();
```

I want to know how these objects are stored and if there is an ID associated with it?

**EDIT:**
The purpose of this is to know when the object is to keep track of the object when it is created and destroyed. How many of them are present and whether all of them are destroyed properly.

Comment: There isn't a built-in object ID in C++. And your "objects" are really function declarations.

Comment: What do you mean by “object ID”?

Comment: You should edit your question to explain *why* you need such object ids!

Answer (score 2):

If you need unique object ids, you should care about this id yourself. For instance, you could decide that all your objects inherit from a superclass like

```
 class ObjectWithId {
    uint64_t _id;
    static uint64_t _counter_;
 protected:
    ObjectWithId() : _id(++_counter_) {};
 /// etc....
 };
```

However you should be careful and think about what id should have a copy, or a move, etc... BTW, the above class is *not* thread-safe. You might want atomic counters (using e.g. [std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)), etc etc...

Read about [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) / [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) etc etc...

As commented by [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96) you might *sometimes* need [persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) ids. They could be provided by some external mean (e.g. by inserting something new in a database then using the id provided by that database at each C++ object construction), or you could use things like [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), or generate a random string, etc. You could also care about eventually reusing id of destroyed objects.

You could also just want non-unique (but often different) ids, e.g. if you just use them for hash code computation. In practice, you may just want to use some fast [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (perhaps simply `lrand48`) to get them.

Notice that standard C++11 [containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) do *not* require any unique id: they often want some ordering on the contained class (e.g. [std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/)), or just an hash code - with possibly an equality test - (e.g. [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)) of it, and they always give the possibility (thru optional template arguments) to give explicitly a compare and/or an hash function.

BTW, a good tool to hunt [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) is [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (or some proprietary equivalent). You probably should learn more about [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) and the C++ standard [`<memory>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/) header.

Comment: If that object instances represent something, that should be used cross process boundaries this solution won't help much. It should at least been mentioned that e.g. database engines, or UUID mechanisms also provide _Object-ID_'s.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Thanks, I improved my answer.